# AWS CLI cp - can you read before cp has completed

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

A debate has been going round the office as to whether you will be able to read a partially copied file on EC2 when using the AWS CLI cp command to sync files from S3.

Does anyone know whether this is true? And is there anyway to mitigate the risk other than copying file into temporary location prior to moving to desired location?

Process already contains checksum check on some files but not all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Amazon S3 never adds partial objects

Until an upload completes, the content that was being uploaded is not technically "in" the bucket.

S3, as you likely know, is not a hierarchical filesystem. It has at least two significant components, the backing store and the index which, unlike in a typical filesystem, are separate... so when you're writing an object, you're not really writing it "in place." Uploading an object saves the object to the backing store, and then adds it to the bucket's index, which is used by GET and other requests to fetch the stored data and metadata for retrieval.

With no entry in the index, the object is not accessible. So you're good. Downloading an object that hasn't finished uploading yet is impossible. The object, technically, doesn't yet exist.

AWS Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html).

Comment: This is more the other side S3 to EC2 using cp command can you read the file from EC2 before it has copied through from S3?